Are these cases counted as Zihar?
Assalamualaikum
Are these cases counted as Zihar?

The wife calls her husband as "Father" and the husband accepts the call (say "yes") with the intention of the Zihar.
The husband calls his own sister but intends that he is calling his own wife as intention of the Zihar.

